# How to send emails from typo3 v6.2

Tags: php, email, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am working with an extension in typo3 v6.2.
In that extension i need to send emails to corresponding email address.
Is normal `mail` function can use to send emails from typo3 v6.2?
Or is there any other method please let me know.

I have

```
$to = $to_email;
$subject = $email_subject;
$message= $email_message;
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

Is this work in typo3 v6?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Typo3 uses php so you can use php functions. Why don't you simply try this and see for yourself if it works or not?

Comment: @Bowdzone thank you for your response. Am new to typo3 and am working it in my local. so i am not able to use the 'mail()'. And i am not aware of any other built in functions in typo3 for mailing. As you said i'll keep going with 'mail()'. thank you :)

Comment: This qus regarding typo3 v6.2.x and may be have different operations for mailing purpose. I have searched about it and got nothing relevant ans to me .That's why i posted the ans here Am here looking for most simplest method to send simple emails in typo3 v6.2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TYPO3 has built in functions for sending e-mails and I would recommend to use the provided classes, since it includes all configuration setup (eg. SMTP auth, correct setting of e-mail headers) which could be configured in TYPO3 install tool.

Usage is quite easy and the example below is taken directly from the [Core API documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Mail/Index.html)

```
$mail = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
$mail->setFrom(array($email => $name));
$mail->setTo(array($email => $name));
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBody($body);
$mail->send();
```

You should prefer this method over using PHP's mail yourself. The TYPO3 core's implementation (using the [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) class) implements mailing according to the specification and therefore sends the necessary headers and data to make it highly probable that the e-mail will arrive at most mail servers.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I'll try dis one. and let me  know that php mail() operation is wrong in typo3 v6.2 ? because I already using it my other core php operations.

Comment: works fine in 8.7 version !!

Comment: can you please explain where this piece of code is supposed to be put? I have a plain HTML element and I want to send data via email. I find your explanation everywhere but nobody mentions WHERE to put this?

Comment: You need to put the code e.g. in a controller or a service in a TYPO3 extension